# hSite has no css on mobile

Tags: css, security, hacked

Our WP site got hacked and we've been working with our hosting to clean all malware etc.  However, now the site appears on desktop fine, but on mobile it looks as though all the css is stripped.  Here's the site: http://italiancottage.pleaseproof.com/

Comment: On mobile your static resources seem to be redirected to another site (in russian, game downloads, so probably malware). Seem you are not done with cleanup there. :( Unfortunately not in scope here, continue to bug your hosting, needs hands-on access.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Where do you recommend I post this forum topic?

Comment: Essentially this is not the kind of a problem that gets solved by posting on the internet about it. You need professional with specific security expertise working on it hands-on, either from your hosting company or hired / otherwise procured.